# Click module error in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, click-packages

I get the following error message on doing `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Preparing to unpack .../click_0.4.46+16.10.20170607.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+16.10.20170607.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Job for click-system-hooks.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status click-system-hooks.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
click-system-hooks.service couldn't start.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+16.10.20170607.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`dpkg-query -l click python3-click`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  click          0.4.45.1+16. amd64        Click packages
un  python3-click  <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

`readlink -f /usr/bin/python3`:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

`ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click_package`:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click_package': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -l click python3-click`, `readlink -f /usr/bin/python3`, and `ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click_package`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ended up fixing it with a

```
sudo apt remove python3-click-package
sudo apt install python3-click-package
```

Comment: I thought I had a path issue, I just realized that's me testing a ansible-silo docker something on another term at the same time. My OS's all fine.

Comment: sudo apt remove python3-click-package
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 zoom : Depends: libxcb-xtest0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the faulty package with:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install python3-click
```